# The sidebar and console of VSCODE are not positioned properly, and the console blocks the display of sidebar files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I encountered a problem. When I first started using vscode, the position of the console and the side was the position of the picture below, so that the console would not block the display of the sidebar files.

[image: 1]

But then I don't know what to set, the console will fill the bottom, and when I want to use the console, it will block the preview sidebar file, like the picture below

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

In the top menu go to  View -> Appearance -> Align Panel -> Center.